dateTimeOffset: UTC + zero offset OR LocalTime with UTC offset
I would like to standardize how dateTimeOffset(3) is stored in our SQL Server tables.
So trying to understand what are the advantage/disadvantage of storing date and time as  LocalTime with UTC offset as opposed to UTC date time + zero offset
Note :

Future schedules are out of scope. For that local date time is a must.
It is only about storage not about displaying time to the end user.
Our app servers run in UTC


And your question is?

UTC is really just a common agreed upon zone to store and perform datetime math against. XXX could have been just as easily chosen. One advantage is that it never changes, thusly one side of the equation remains constant.

@DaleK "trying to understand what are the advantage/disadvantage of storing date and time as LocalTime with UTC offset as opposed to UTC date time + zero offset"

Thats not a question, a question would be "what are the adv/dis..." but then its not suitable either, because its opinion based. Which one meets your business requirements?

@RossBush Would you propose any other benifit? Because with dateTimeOffset if you store local time +/- utc offset you can capture from where the information originated. Furhtermore, you can write select query to compare time represented in EST and you will get all the records which represent the same time regardless what offset dateTimeOffset records are stored.e.g: select ..time='2024-04-02 10:00:00.123 -04:00' will show this record too 2024-04-02 14:00:00.123 +00:00 .  Given both of these points what is the advantage of storing in UTC.

Storing as UTC is unambiguous as to when an event has (or will) occur and the duration between two times is consistent, but you have to deal with time zones and DST (summer time) adjustments when presenting as local time or when grouping data by local day. In the US Eastern time zone, which local-day includes 04:30 depends on whether DST is active or not. Storing as local time works for an application that only has to deal with a single time zone, but you will have discontinuities when DST (summer time) start and ends. A 00:00 - 08:00 work shift might be 8, 7, or 9 hours. ...

... The DATETIMEOFFSET is a representation that includes the positive aspects of both, but your application must be consistently date-time-offset aware.  (Suggested watching "The Problem with Time & Timezones - Computerphile".

The vast, vast majority of the time, you should store values as simple UTC. It can further be helpful to name the columns indicating this is the expected practice.
If you expect the offset will always be 0, there's no advantage to this over a basic DateTime column that's already always UTC and the 0 offset is just assumed.
The time to store as UTC + non-zero offset is when the original offset is relevant to the data. One example is to do things like show how many sales happened per day, where "day" is defined as the local day where the purchase is made, rather than the UTC day or the offset of the corporate headquarters. To do this correctly, you still need an original offset stored with the timestamp, especially for a web store front where a sale could come from anywhere at any time. Even here, if this were an actual requirement, I might instead store it as two columns, one for TimestampUTC, and one for TimestampLocal, as this would make it much easier to group by a Date value from the local timestamp, and not worry about the offset. But this is just one example... there are a number of reasons the original local offset might be (or become) important.
This goes against common recommendation, but I have also worked with organizations that now and always will exist entirely within a single time zone and store data in simple DateTime columns where everything is assumed to be that time zone. It works for them, but again: don't make this your default (or even second, third, or fourth) option; it'll almost always come back to bite you in some way. You can certainly always show data in whatever time zone you want on the web, in an app, or in reports... but be very certain before you store it that way. And be cautious where you go to get approval for a decision on this, as even the most senior people in the business will likely say, "Oh yeah, we'll only ever be Eastern time, let's store everything that way" without actually understanding these issues.
